# Firefox preferences for file download in robotframework(Python)

Tags: robotframework

Anyone can provide me complete code for file download in firefox browser. Actually, I'm new to robotframework.

Comment: do you mean you are clicking on download file in firefox, select download location and downloading it?

Comment: Yes.I don't know how to write code for that in robotframework

Comment: you can use a combination of "KeyPress" which would help you to click on download link, to enter your download location you can use "SendKeys" which will allow you to type path and hit enter key.

Comment: I hope you are trying it on a windows machine?

Comment: Yes.do you have any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the way to achieve it. 
This is jut an overview and not the exact code

Robot File: Download.txt

```
Library    KeyStorke.py
Library    Selenium2Library 

Download file
    Click Button    Download
    enter path    <path>
    hit enter
```

Python library: KeyStorke.py

```
import SendKeys

def hit_enter():
    SendKeys.SendKeys("{ENTER}")

def enter_path(path):
    SendKeys.SendKeys(path)
```

Comment: Actually,I am new to robot framework,Can I get completed code?

Comment: haha! that can't be done unless I have UI to check that. Not sure if you can enter a chat either?

Comment: I am referring  this link :https://catalog.data.gov/dataset?res_format=CSV

Comment: not sure how that link can help you. but to know about robotframework and selenium, nothing is better than their documentation: http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html